# strange issue with dxComponentPrinter1

Tags: delphi, devexpress

This should probably get posted under 'believe it or not' questions but ...As soon as I put dxComponentPrinter1 (devexpress) on the form my function ceases to work :

```
Function GetUserFromWindows: string;
Var
   UserName : string;
   UserNameLen : Dword;
Begin
   UserNameLen := 100;
   SetLength(userName, UserNameLen) ;
   If GetUserName(PChar(UserName), UserNameLen) Then
     Result := Copy(UserName,1,UserNameLen - 1)
   Else
     Result := 'Unknown';
end;
```

When I remove it (dxComponentPrinter1) then it works ok. The error I get, when the dxComponentPrinter1 is on the form is this :

> [dcc32 Error] Unit3.pas(101): E2034 Too many actual parameters [dcc32
>   Error] Unit3.pas(101): E2012 Type of expression must be BOOLEAN

Delphi XE6 underlines in red the line :

> GetUserName(PChar(UserName), UserNameLen)

If I remove the function then everything compiles ok. No error.
Has anybody encountered this before ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you add the component to the form, a devExpress unit is added to your uses clause. This unit defines a function named `GetUserName` that your code now sees rather than the one you want to use declared in the `Windows` unit.

You could deal with this by fully qualifying the call to `GetUserName`. Either

```
Windows.GetUserName
```

or

```
Winapi.Windows.GetUserName
```

depending on how you named the `Windows` unit when you used it.

Personally, I'd be looking to see this `GetUserFromWindows` function declared in a low-level unit rather than a GUI unit.

If you want to make a function that reads the user name and can handle any length of name, then you could go for this possibly over-engineered version:

```
function UserName: string;
var
  Len: DWORD;
begin
  Len := 0;
  Win32Check(not GetUserName(nil, Len) and (GetLastError=ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER));
  SetLength(Result, Len-1);
  Win32Check(GetUserName(PChar(Result), Len));
end;
```

Note that I've not fully qualified here because I assume that you'll move this function into a different unit that uses no dexExpress UI components.

Comment: I think I explained that

Comment: If Winapi.Windows.GetUserName(PChar(UserName), UserNameLen) Then ...seems to work...Thank you!

Comment: Though at first it all seemed strange, this is actually a very good question. I would not have thought in a million years that the printer component also uses 'GetUserName'. David, you are a genious!:)

Comment: I wouldn't say that. Once you've encountered uses related scope problems once, you never forget.